# No package shown in my JApplet?

Tags: java, netbeans, package, japplet

I am trying to set up NetBeans for on my personal laptop for Java applications. I am a beginner programmer and I'm trying to figure out all the basics.

In this application I'm trying to make a `JApplet`. So I open a Java Class Library and add a new `JApplet`. But when the `JApplet` comes up, there is no package. Just a `package ;` and an error message.

What exactly is a package and how do I fix this problem?

Comment: please post the exact error message. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html for packages

Answer (score 0):

A package is a type of organizational structure for java. Basically, for a class in a folder:

```
src/com/myperson/someproject/SomeClass.java
```

the package is `com.myperson.someproject`. The package may be blank (`src/SomeClass.java`) in which case the `package` line is skipped in the code.